# Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac' for ionic corodva app

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3

I am developing an ionic v3 with cordova app for android platform.

When I am running `ionic cordova build platform --verbose` I am getting compilation failed in build -

```
platforms\android\app\src\main\java\com\ionicframework\cordova\webview\IonicWebViewEngine.java:11: error: package android.support.annotation does not exist
platforms\android\app\src\main\java\com\ionicframework\cordova\webview\IonicWebViewEngine.java:114: error: cannot find symbol @RequiresApi
```

Below are configuations-

> gradle.properties

```
cdvCompileSdkVersion=android-28
cdvMinSdkVersion=21
cdvBuildToolsVersion=28.0.3
android.useDeprecatedNdk=true
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

> ionic info

```
Ionic:

   ionic (Ionic CLI)  : 4.6.0 (C:\Users\1231083\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic)
   Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
   @ionic/app-scripts : 3.2.1

Cordova:

   cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.1.2 (cordova-lib@8.1.1)
   Cordova Platforms     : android 7.1.2
   Cordova Plugins       : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.1.3, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 2.3.1, (and 4 other plugins)

System:

   Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1 (C:\Users\1231083\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk)
   NodeJS            : v10.11.0 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe)
   npm               : 6.5.0
   OS                : Windows 7
```

Please help.

Comment: Gradle version used here is 4.6

Comment: Solved! How? - I modified the import package name from `android.support.annotation` to `androidx.annotation` by using AndroidX libs (check `android.useAndroidX=true` in `gradle.properties`) in `IonicWebViewEngine.java`

Comment: Strange, I've got this error on existed project after cleanup platform/android.
About your solution - do you mean to change .java source file?

Comment: @Drapaster Yes. I modified the .java source file. :)